# json_decode and E numbers in PHP

Tags: php, json

I have tried solutions given in other threads, but unfortunately not yet come to a solution.

The json that I am retrieving is:

```
{"foo": [
        {"coo": "2013-01-01 13:42:21",
            "moo": 0.00008200,
        }
    ]
}
```

I am using the following code to parse it:

```
$jsonString=preg_replace('/([^\\\])" *: *([0-9]{10,})(,|})/', '$1":"$2"$3', $jsonString);

$jsonString=json_decode($jsonString, true);
```

However, the value for moo is showing as: 8.02E-5

What can I do to rectify this?

Comment: isn't that correct? `8.02E-5` = `0.00008200`

Comment: What exactly is that `preg_replace` supposed to do?

Comment: the preg_replace is a hack to convert numbers to a string so that it doesn't truncate. That is a solution given in other threads.

Comment: @bansi: I am confused why nobody answered you: 8.02E-5 is not equal to 0.0008200, which is 8.2E-5. However, since the OP didn't correct you, I wonder if the answers actually satisfy him or her.

Answer (score 4):

PHP uses scientific notation when you exceed the floating point precision limit that can be set in the php config options.

Try adding:

```
ini_set('precision',20);
```

for example, to change your floating point precision limit to 20.

Comment: I am on a windows server, so put:
precision    =  20
However, now I am getting:
8.2000000000000000948E-5

Comment: hmmm, in that case I would try rounding the number to the precision that you actually need using round(), 2nd (optional) parameter lets you specify floating point value precision, see http://us3.php.net/manual/en/function.round.php

Comment: too add to my comment above, it might be easier to access / modify the value of "moo" by reading the json string into a native php array using json_decode($jsonString), and then iterate / alter as necessary

Answer (score 3):

You could make use of [`sprintf()`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.sprintf.php)

```
<?php
$json='{"foo":
    [
    {   "coo": "2013-01-01 13:42:21",
        "moo": 0.00008200
    }
    ]
}';

$jsonString=json_decode($json, true);
echo sprintf('%.6f', $jsonString['foo'][0]['moo']);// "prints" 0.000082
```

Comment: This would lose any precision that has been lost by the json_decode.